# GridControl delete multiple row and update the record in database

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, ms-access-2010, gridcontrol

Greeting,

I'm using DevExpress for for VB.NET development, I have this GridControl with checkbox to select multiple rows.

Now after I select multiple rows, I use GridViewName.DeleteSelectedRows() to delete the row but it just delete in the GridControl but not the data inside the database.

I use the below method to populate data into my GridControl:

```
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT tblProduct.prod_id, tblProduct.prod_model, tblCategory.cat_name, tblProduct.prod_quantity, tblProduct.prod_cost, tblProduct.prod_price" _
                                        & " FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblCategory.cat_id = tblProduct.prod_category", openConn())
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        da.Fill(dt)

        GridViewName.DataSource = dt
```

How do I update my data in my database for multiple row deletion?

Regards,
Milo

Comment: if a control is bound to a datasource, you should delete from the data source not the control.

Comment: Yea the question is how do I get the prod_id for the multiple rows I selected for deletion?

Comment: The prodid should be a part of the grid, then you would have that I'd. Put it in a column and make it invisible....

Comment: Yes I did populate it there and make it invisible, I mean how do I retrieve the multiple rows ID that I selected? @__@

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which explains how to obtain selected row IDs:

```
        Dim rowHandles As Integer() = gridView1.GetSelectedRows()
    Dim rowKeys As Object() = New Object(rowHandles.Length - 1){}
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While i < rowHandles.Length
        rowKeys(i) = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandles(i), "KeyFieldValue")
        i += 1
    Loop
```